# How can I read the attributes assigned to the properties of a class?

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, class, class-attributes

Given the following class

```
Public Class Customer
    Inherits XPBaseObject

    Private _CustomerID As Integer = -1

    <Key(True), _
    Custom("AllowNull", "True"), _
    Custom("AutoInc", "True"), _
    DbType("int")> Public Property CustomerID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _CustomerID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            SetPropertyValue(Of Integer)("CustomerID", _CustomerID, value)
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

How can I read the custom attibutes of the `CustomerID` or any other property?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection:

```
Dim properties As PropertyInfo() = Me.[GetType]().GetProperties()
For Each prop As PropertyInfo In properties
    Dim attribute As Attribute = prop.GetCustomAttributes(GetType(Attribute), True)_
        .OfType(Of Attribute)()_
        .FirstOrDefault()
Next
```